# Huawei Linux driver on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: usb-modem, source-packages

installing the driver for the Huawei Vodafone K3772 key in Ubu 13.04 I get the following error:

```
"make: *** [install] Errore 2
Install NDIS driver failed.
The compiling environment is not all ready.
Please check gcc, make and kernel buid(/lib/modules/3.8.0-22-generic/build) to be all installed?
Now please enter any key to finish other installations.
NDIS is disabled, and only Modem can be used".
These packages gcc, make, and others are installed.
```

I have another laptop with Mint 14 KDE and the installation is successful ane the key work fine.
What can miss on 13.04 to finish the installation from source?

Thank's

Comment: Have you installed build-essential?

Comment: I get the same error!

Answer (score 2):

**Download the modified driver from [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzmA9dL81DBAVmpvQkZtd200eVE/view?usp=sharing) link.**

**Installation**

- Extract the archive to *Desktop*
  `$ cd ~/Desktop`
  `$ tar -xvf Linux\ Driver\ 4.19.19.00\(Modified\).tar.gz`
- Change to the extracted directory whose name is *driver*
  `$ cd driver`
- Switch to *root* and make the script named *install* executable
  `$ su`
  `$ chmod +x install`
- Install the script
  `$ ./install`
- The *NDIS driver installation failed* error will not occur. Instead it will show *NDIS driver installation successful*.

**Creating a Mobile Broadband connection**

- Go to *Settings -> Network -> Mobile Broadband* and click *Add new connection*
- Follow the steps which involves selecting the country, operator etc.

Next time if you insert the modem it will be detected properly and you can connect to the Mobile Broadband connection you created previously by clicking the *Network icon* on the system tray.

Comment: Its working in Ubuntu 14.04 with Huawei E173 3G Modem.

Answer (score 1):

I found same issue, and could modify. Please try a below patch.

```
diff -ru driver_org/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c
--- driver_org/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c 2012-06-13 21:13:08.000000000 +0900
+++ driver/ndis_driver/ndis_src/src/hw_cdc_driver.c     2013-05-25 03:18:23.335755961 +0900
@@ -2715,7 +2715,7 @@
     // set up our own records
     net = alloc_etherdev(sizeof(*dev));
     if (!net) {
-        dbg ("can't kmalloc dev");
+//      dbg ("can't kmalloc dev");
         goto out;
     }
```

Cheers

Comment: after several attempts and after reinstallig usb_modeswitch, I managed to connect the key in an appropriate way and with the maximum connection speed.I configured usb_modeswitch manually by following the instructions found on the site http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/device_reference.txt. I do not know why it is so complicated to install a usb stick in linux!

Comment: Please how do you apply the patch?

Comment: see the post http://askubuntu.com/questions/323031/how-to-install-ndis-driver-for-huawei-mobile-broadband-devices/368669#368669 for NDIS driver problem