# Ubuntu not detecting Huawei EC178 Modem

Tags: usb-modem, huawei

I have a Huawei EC178 3G modem. I had huawei mobile partner installed. I removed It's autostart launcher and indicator-application-service from startup applications. As a result Ubuntu have stopped detecting my modem. To fix this I tried following steps but no success.

1. Re-entered these two applications in startup.
2. Re-installed Huawei mobile partner.
3. Tried what is suggested on [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1969322).
4. Tried what is suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362815/configuring-usb-modem-huawei-ec156-in-ubuntu-13-10) too.

Modem manager is not detecting it either. Ubuntu only detects modem as storage device.
I tried to connect my modem on an other system to confirm whether this issue is with device it self, but device was connected successfully on that system.

Ouput of `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 413c:8133 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 5720 VZW Mobile Broadband (EVDO Rev-A) Minicard GPS Port
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 12d1:1505 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Output of `usb-devices`

```
T:  Bus=07 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=12d1 ProdID=1505 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=HUAÿWEI TECHNOLOGIES
S:  Product=HUAWEI Mobile
S:  SerialNumber=ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

**EDIT**:
It seems that my modem is being detected but not working properly. When I ran `sudo wvdial` console output was:

```
~:\> sudo wvdial
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT#777
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT#777
```

Where it hung on last line. `wvdial.conf` is

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Baud = 460800
New PPPD = yes
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
ISDN = 0
Phone = #777
Password = ptcl
Username = vwireless@ptcl.com
```

Comment: follow the answers in this question and install the applications and see. http://askubuntu.com/q/380650/296776